# 「お気に入りのタグ」かつ未回答の質問を検索したい

Tags: サポート, 検索

私が望むものは、こんなフィルタです。

1. **「私のタグで未回答の質問」　の　更新日時降順**
   [/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags)
   では、票の高い順だと思いますが。 9票 0回答のコメント解決( [/questions/7579](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/7579) )
   のような質問が上位を締めていくのが気がかりです。
2. **「回答のない未回答の質問」　で　私のタグのもの**
   「私のタグの回答のない質問」と言い換えてもよいでしょう。
   tab=mytagsかつnoanswersというのは、出来ないものでしょうか。
   あるいは、1つ1つタグを巡回しても構わないので
   /questions/tagged/hogehoge?tab=noanswers
   みたいなことが出来ないでしょうか。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `intags:mine` は、お気に入りとマークしたタグに現れる投稿のみを返します。
>
> https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/searching

この機能を使えば次のような検索が可能です。

- お気に入りに登録したタグを新着順に
  https://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=intags%3amine
- 〃タグのうち未回答（`answers:0`）
  https://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?q=intags%3Amine+answers%3A0

なお、検索画面の右側にある「高度な検索のヒント」をクリックすると `answers` などのオプションが一覧できます（`intags:mine` はヘルプにしか書いてありませんが）。

Comment: お気に入り！そういえばそれもでした。無事解決しました。